# Modelling Conditional Rules in Relational Database

Tags: database-design, relational-database, relationship

Instead of a lengthy list of if/then conditions.. How does one go about representing these conditions, or *rules*, in a relational database.

For example: Everytime i make a pb&j sandwhich, I **constantly** use `x` slices of bread, `y` amount of Peanut Butter, and `z` amount of Jelly. I want to simply record that i made 1 pb&j sandwhich (while still able to account for ingredients!). When i change my recipe, I would like to be able to update a ratio, -attribute,property, or field,? - instead of modify the conditional statements; in case per say i have 1million different sandwich recipes.

The obvious answer to me is to create a table for each "sandwich" and list each ingredient and its ratio as a record? This seems primitive, Im hoping there is a "cooler" way to do this?

Please share your ideas! Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go over the relations before we try and create any [relational tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

- A recipe contains one or more ingredients.
- An ingredient can go into one or more recipes.

So, let's create the entity tables first.

```
Ingredient
----------
Ingredient ID
Ingredient name

Recipe
------
Recipe ID
Recipe name
Recipe description
Recipe instructions
Recipe number serves
```

Ok, now we create a relation table that ties recipes and ingredients together

```
Recipe Ingredient
-----------------
Recipe ID
Ingredient ID
Ingredient quantity
Ingredient unit of measure
```

The primary (clustering) key to Recipe Ingredient is (Recipe ID, Ingredient ID).  You'll also need a unique index on (Ingredient ID, Recipe ID).

Comment: I already had the m2m table, idk why i didnt think to add the qty there. Using django ORM built in m2m was making me lazy i suppose. Deleted the m2m table created by the orm and manually added one with qty! Thx :P